# Magento Installation Wizard Errors

Tags: php, mysql, magento, ssh, pear

I'm trying to install magento in a subdirectory on my hostgator server. I did the necessary pre install through SSH and am now trying to finish the install through the magento installation wizard through a browser. However, I keep get these errors:

```
pear/Console_Getopt requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.7.1
pear/PEAR requires package "pear/Console_Getopt" (recommended version 1.2.3)
magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers requires package "pear/PEAR" (version >= 1.6.2)
magento-core/Lib_Google_Checkout requires package "magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers" (version >= 1.0.18800)
magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules requires package "magento-core/Lib_Google_Checkout" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3, excluded versions: 1.4.3)
magento-core/Mage_All_Latest requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.2.0)
magento-core/Mage_Core_Adminhtml requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.2.0)
magento-core/Interface_Adminhtml_Default requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Adminhtml" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3.0, excluded versions: 1.4.3.0)
magento-core/Interface_Frontend_Default requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3, excluded versions: 1.4.3)
magento-core/Interface_Install_Default requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3, excluded versions: 1.4.3)
magento-core/Mage_Centinel requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3, excluded versions: 1.4.3)
magento-core/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3, excluded versions: 1.4.3)
magento-core/Phoenix_Moneybookers requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3, excluded versions: 1.4.3)
magento-core/Find_Feed requires package "magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules" (version >= 1.4.2.0, version <= 1.4.3)
magento-core/Lib_Js_Calendar requires package "magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers" (version >= 1.0.18800)
magento-core/Lib_Js_Prototype requires package "magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers" (version >= 1.0.18800)
magento-core/Mage_Downloader requires package "magento-core/Lib_Js_Prototype" (version >= 1.6.0.3.0, version <= 1.6.1, excluded versions: 1.6.1)
magento-core/Lib_Js_Mage requires package "magento-core/Lib_Js_Prototype" (version >= 1.6.0.3.3, version <= 1.6.1, excluded versions: 1.6.1)
magento-core/Lib_Js_Ext requires package "magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers" (version >= 1.0.18800, version <= 1.0.18800)
magento-core/Lib_Js_TinyMCE requires package "magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers" (version >= 1.0.18800)
magento-core/Lib_ZF requires package "magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers" (version >= 1.0.18800)
magento-core/Lib_Varien requires package "magento-core/Lib_ZF" (version >= 1.10.8.0, version <= 1.10.9.0, excluded versions: 1.10.9.0)
magento-core/Lib_ZF_Locale requires package "magento-core/Mage_Pear_Helpers" (version >= 1.0.18800)
Install Errors
No valid packages found
PEAR ERROR: install failed
```

I submitted a ticket to Hostgator and they are asking what packages I need installed. If I'm reading this correctly I need them to update the PEAR Installer correct?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they need to update PEAR and you need to install those missing packages. If you have cPanel at HostGator you should be able to install packages yourself.

Comment: The problem is that it shows PEAR as 1.9.1 when I check it's version on the server but the script thinks it is at 1.7.1 

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: It might be your path to PEAR that is wrong. You could be using a different version of PEAR than what you are checking.

Comment: Looks like Magento is trying to use a local version of PEAR instead of what is on the server... I've been talking to hostgator support and they are trying to figure it out.

Comment: That could be the one installed from within cPanel. I am most likely sure it is from cPanel.